# as3 Air 2.5 Linux PrintJob Addpage trowh error nº 2057

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I heve the next lines of code:

```
_printJob = new PrintJob();
        if (_printJob.start2(null, _printWorkSettings.usePageSetupDialog)) {
            MonsterDebugger.trace(this, new Date());
            try {
                _printJob.addPage(objectoToPrint, null, _printWorkSettings.jobOptions);
            } catch (error:Error) {
                MonsterDebugger.trace(this, error + "/n" + error.getStackTrace() + "/n" + error.toString());
            }
            _printJob.send();
            MonsterDebugger.trace(this, 'job sended to printer');
            MonsterDebugger.trace(this, new Date());
        }
```

When it is executed on a Linux machine running AIR 2.5 I get the error 2057, the I check the time between the start2 method and the send and is on the same second. I also checked that the property objectToPrint is a MovieClip.

This works on a windows PC, and I'm unable to do a better debugging than the one is possible using the trace of MonsterDebugger, so any ideas on how can I get more information about why addPage is returning this error or any information about the printJob on Linux?

By the way, I also tryed:

```
_printJob.addPage(objectoToPrint);
```

And I get the same result.

The property _printWorkSettings.usePageSetupDialog is always true so I now showing the print menu for the user.

Thansk in advance folks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, there is only one printer on the linux system and was not setted a default so addpage  trowh errors.

I get a inspiration on this [forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/515196)